# Testing a sinatra route with csrf protection

Tags: rspec, sinatra, rack

I'm trying to to test routes for a basic sinatra app but having my test requests fail due to a csrf protection error `Rack::Csrf::InvalidCsrfToken`.
These routes are typically hit by a client side application, which includes a csrf token via a `<meta>` tag.
I've tried accessing the csrf token via Rack::Csrf.token, but I don't have access to `env` (or at least I don't know how to access `env` within my rpsec tests), and have not experienced success.

**app.rb**

```
use Rack::Csrf, raise: true

put '/api/events/:id' do
  # ... code that updates an event ...
end
```

**example_spec.rb**

```
it "adds an event to the current user" do
  user = Helpers.authorized_user
  session = {user_id: user.id}

  put '/events/1/join', {}, {'rack.session' => session, :xhr => true}
do
```

How do I circumvent/appease Rack:CSRF when testing these routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple to do by creating and passing a secret HTTP header variable. [Check the docs](https://github.com/baldowl/rack_csrf)

```
use Rack::Csrf, :skip_if => lambda { |request|
  if settings.development?
      request.env.key?('HTTP_X_VERY_SPECIAL_HEADER')
  else
      false # Don't skip outside of testing
  end
}

put '/api/events/:id' do
    # ... code that updates an event ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!I guess I could only set `skip_if` in my application if I am in a development environment, I would prefer a way of doing this inside the testing framework rather than my application code itself. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @NickTomlin Doing this inside the testing framework will create technical debt, so it's probably not the best way to go (IMHO). I've updated my answer to only skip CSRF checks if you are running in development mode, it might not be what you want, but hopefully can point you in the right direction

Comment: I've gone ahead and disabled csrf in the testing environment instead of using a special csrf key but the idea is essentially the same. Thanks!

Comment: `use Rack::Csrf, raise: true, skip_if: ->(req) { req.env['rack.test'] }` worked for me